# How secure Web services in android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i have search many time to how secure my web service in my android project but always got a single answer set ProGuard in Gradle file.

But i don't have idea about ProGuard.

Please any one can idea about ProGuard so help me and explain with example step by step.

I have already read ProGuard rules on developer site (https://developer.android.com/)

Below code inside my Gradle file

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

above code through not secure my web services.

Comment: you have to make 'minifyEnabled true'

Comment: What do you mean by "how secure my web service in my android project" . Proguard is used to secure files so that others cant access. It does not deal with securing web service ?

Comment: i have set Proguard in my project and after generate sign apk, but i decompile this apk using this site http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk so i have found my web service as it is.

Comment: there is no single point to 'secure web services with ProGuard'. Anyone can just sniff the traffic from the device and see endpoint, paths, requests and response. Just protect webservice itself, not the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find a solution...

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

We can update above code build.gradle file and sync your project

Answer (score 0):

Proguard can help you in minifying and code obfuscation 
Details here 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html

However to secure the webservice, you need to implement SSL authentication. You will get great details here, 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html
In case you are stuck with any specific problem during implementation then post it here.

Regards
AShish

Comment: I have read this site but i don't get any thing, it's possible to give sample code.